# Unit test context configuration spring

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, configuration

I am doing unit tests for a rest controller, which is only a small part of a bigger application.
Ideally I would like to use a mocking framework to ensure that the test are unitary. I would mock the manager and the dao.
However that would require to have different configurations for the rest controller class that make him use a different manager depending if we are in test context or in application context.
The mocks are defined in context-test.xml.

This is what I have done so far :
**Test RestController**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(locations = "classpath:/META-INF/spring/context-test.xml")
@WebIntegrationTest
public class MyRestControllerTest extends AbstractTransactionnalTest {

  @Autowired
  private IManager manager;

  @Test
  // my unit tests
}
```

**RestController**

```
@RestController
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:/META-INF/spring/context-test.xml",
                                             "classpath:/META-INF/spring/context-application.xml"})
@RequestMapping("/me")
class MyRestController {

  @Autowired
  private IManager manager;

  // Content of my controller
  }
```

The main issue with my solution so far :
- I dont know how to tell the RestController wich context to use. (I only want to use one context at a time)

**Is there a better solution to do this ?**

Comment: Your controller class should have no knowledge of the application configuration at all. That belongs in your launcher (either your `main` or your test configuration).

Comment: AFAIK spring also supports DI via constructor. Why not use this?

Comment: @TimothyTruckle Ideally I would like not to use the constructor as I am using the builder design pattern. But that could be another way to solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @chrylis. The problem here I think may be your class design.

If your `MyRestController` class is dependent on knowing *which* context is passed in, seems like this would be a Spring/DI anti-pattern. The whole point of DI is that the class "passively" handles the context with correct behavior in the first place.

Any injected objects should simply be created/handled correctly by the injecting context.

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding a `setManager()` method, this would allow you to set the manager in your controller to a 'mocked' manager.

Comment: I don't quite see how that would work as I only have one instance of manager in my application and it is `@Autowired`.  I can't acces my RestController in the test.